# VirtualBox Linux does not return ping and host machine cannot access apache on that guest

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtualbox

I have a Windows7 as host and Debian as guest via VirtualBox. everything worked just fine until I did `apt-get update` on my guest machine and I think it scrambled some settings (not sure though...).

My current VB network settings are:

Adapter 1: Bridged Adapter

Adapter 2: Host-only adapter

My guest machine works fine, has internet connection and I can access it files via `My Computer > Network`, yet I cannot ping the guest machine nor access its apache webserver, any ideas?

Comment: perhaps the debian's firewall close the ICMP service. Try to scan the guest using nMap and see whether the port 80 is open or not.

Comment: How can I scan the guest if I can't even access its ip? see this: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2hxviog.jpg

Comment: wait a minute?first of all..why do you use 2 adapter?is 1 adapter not enough?is there any particular reason?

Comment: According to tutorials I read online they say to configure 2 Adapters [for local sharing and outgoing internet connections]

Comment: Wooho Issue Solved! Using only 1 Adapter as `Bridged Adapter` with the correct adapter selected [ethernet connection] and works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to hear it dude. :)
1 network adapter usually enough for 'normal' purpose. I use more than 1 network adapter when I want to simulate more complicated computer network plan, like I want to have experiment with proxy, router, dns etc. Just make sure you understand the networking mode that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yogipriyo, removed the second adapter and selected only 1 `bridged adapter` and it works.